# Index.html is not loading with data after running gulp ngdocs command

Tags: angularjs, documentation, gulp, ngdoc

I have executed gulp ngdocs command and docs folder got created within the project folder structure.when I try to run the index.html the data is not getting loaded but when I try to run one of the js file present in the partials folder the data is getting loaded.Am I missing something.Kindly help.

Contents inside the Docs folder
*css,partials,js,fonts folder and index.html*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, tried checking the console errors after loading the index.html.Few js files were missing in the JS folder inside the DOCS folder.

Comment: But aren't this JS files automatically generated in the task? I have a similar issue, where angular.js is missing.

Comment: yes it should be created automatically, but somehow it got missed i guess.Did u add angular.js and try?